# Characterize all continuous functions from locally compact space into $\Bbb{R}$ that extend to their one point compactification.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact space. Let $Y$ be its one-point compactification. Characterize all continuous functions

$$f:X \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$$

such that $f$ extends to $Y$.

So first to get a hold of this problem I wanna work with $X=\Bbb{R}$ as $\Bbb{R}$ Is locally compact. Is it safe to say the one point compactification of $\Bbb{R}$ Is given as

$$\Bbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}.$$

If this is the case I wanna say the functions are those who vanish at $\infty$. Then to generalize this can I say these $f$'s are those that vanish at the point you tackle on? So are they all of the form

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$$

where $g(x) \neq 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)=\infty$

So for example $\frac{1}{e^x}$ would work?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would require the functions to vanish at infinity. What about nonzero constant functions?

Comment: so either constant functions at the point you tackle on or that vanish at the point you tackle on? @MPW

Answer (score 1):

This is (almost tautologically) equivalent to having a limit at infinity: there is some $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some compact $K \subset X$ such that $f(X - K) \subset (L - \epsilon, L + \epsilon)$. Then $f$ extends by $f(\infty) = L$.

Equivalently, $f(x) - L$ vanishes at $\infty$, but a function that vanishes at $\infty$ can certainly also vanish at points of $X$, so you cannot necessarily write $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x) - L}$.